# Get ClientID of a Control Placed INSIDE a DataControl

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listview, clientid

Can anyone help me to get the ClientID of a control which is kept in the ItemTemplate of an DataControl?
My control is like this.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                 <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                    <tr runat="server">
                        <td>Contacts</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" >

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkFlag" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
                    </td>                
                    <td><asp:Label ID="LabelContacts" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("cont_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfGSM" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("cont_gsm") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

I need to get the ClientID of CheckBox from inside this ListView.
Do anyone knows how to do it? Please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work, if you assign it to an attribute of the CheckBox for example, or test it rendering it in the label of the CheckBox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkFlag" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
  onClick="alert('<%# ((Control)Container).FindControl("chkFlag").ClientID %>')" />
```

**P.S.** I just copied from here, search in SO when opening new questions, or do we want to explode their SQL? :D

[How do I find the Client ID of control within an ASP.NET GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128746/how-do-i-find-the-client-id-of-control-within-an-asp-net-gridview)

Answer (score 0):

in the ItemDataBound event handler... you can find the control and get the client id like this

```
((CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("chkFlag")).ClientID
```