# Custom DatePicker not working inside GridView

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am using the following code for date pick field in `ASP.NET`.

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="Date of Birth">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="text_master_dateedit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MemberDOB", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' Width="60%" CssClass="textfoot" ValidationGroup="editing" MaxLength="10" onkeypress="return false;" onkeyup="return false;" oncontextmenu="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></asp:TextBox> &nbsp;
        <a href="javascript:NewCssCal('<%=text_master_dateedit.ClientID %>','DDMMYYYY')"><img id="Img1" alt="Pick a Date" src="Images/cal.png" width="25" height="25" style="vertical-align:middle;" /></a><br />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="requireddateedit" runat="server" ValidationGroup="editing" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="false" ControlToValidate="text_master_dateedit" ErrorMessage="Date required">*Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="label_master_dateview" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MemberDOB", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="text_master_datenew" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MemberDOB", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' Width="60%" CssClass="textfoot" ValidationGroup="adding" MaxLength="10" onkeypress="return false;" onkeyup="return false;" oncontextmenu="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></asp:TextBox> &nbsp;
        <a href="javascript:NewCssCal('<%=text_master_datenew.ClientID %>','DDMMYYYY')"><img id="Img1" alt="Pick a Date" src="Images/cal.png" width="25" height="25" style="vertical-align:middle;" /></a><br />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="requireddatenew" runat="server" ValidationGroup="adding" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="false" ControlToValidate="text_master_datenew" ErrorMessage="Date required">*Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I have the text field and date link within the `GridView` as a `TemplateField`. When I run the code I get the following error.

`Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'text_master_dateedit' does not exist in the current context`

But the same thing works outside `GridView`. How can I solve the issue here of identifying the text field ID within `GridView`? I don't want to use a normal `DatePicker` since I am using this code for all my projects. Any solution with this same code to make this work?

The `NewCssCal` function is a `JavaScript` code that is used for date pick fields in all my projects. It works in all cases except inside `GridView`.

**EDIT**

I also tried using the `ClientIDMode="Static"` and still not working.

In C# i use the below code to access the value of date field since i cannot access it directly when the text field is inside `GridView`. **This works.**

```
protected void gv_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)gv.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    string date = ((TextBox)row.Cells[0].FindControl("text_master_dateedit")).‌​Text;
}
```

Is there a similar way also to access the text field in this line? I want to make this line work. Is there a way to access the ID of the text field `text_master_dateedit` (text field inside gridview) instead of `'<%=text_master_dateedit.ClientID %>'`??

**This not works.**

```
<a href="javascript:NewCssCal('<%=text_master_dateedit.ClientID %>','DDMMYYYY')"><img id="Img1" alt="Pick a Date" src="Images/cal.png" width="25" height="25" style="vertical-align:middle;" /></a>
```

**Page Load**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Session["USER"] != null)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Tab1.CssClass = "Clicked";
                MainView.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("LoginPage.aspx");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Error Occured: Try Again!')", true);
    }
}
```

In Page Load i am only selecting the `Tab1` which is the first tab of the aspx page. I have a total of three `GridView` in the page and three tabs. I am creating the tabs using `<asp:MultiView>`

Comment: You are obviously accessing an item, that doesn't exist at the current time. Would you show us your code behind? Furthermore: When do you receive that message? During Page Load? At Compile Time?

Comment: My back end is a JavaScript function `function NewCssCal(pCtrl, pFormat, pScroller, pShowTime, pTimeMode, pHideSeconds)` that gets the selected date and puts that in the text field. This works normally. Only when i put the text field inside a grid view it is not working. My code behind for the `GridView` contains normal fetching of data and binding it. That also works if i use a normal `Date Picker` using `JQuery`. But i want to make this custom date picker work. Code is working fine. My problem is how to give the ID of text field that is inside GridView to the NewCssCal function.

Comment: I receive this error during Page Load itself. In C# i use the following code to access this text field. `string date = ((TextBox)row.Cells[0].FindControl("text_master_dateedit")).Text;`. I want to do a similar or another method to pass the text field into the NewCssCal function

Comment: well why don't you show us your page load method, when this is where your error occurs?

Comment: I have added the Page Load code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shows that :

> string date =
>   ((TextBox)row.Cells[0].FindControl("text_master_dateedit")).‌​Text;

what is `row` here ??

Can you try this instead:

```
TextBox dateTxt   = (TextBox)GridViewID.Rows[CellIndex].FindControl("text_master_dateedit");
string dateString = dateTxt.Text;
```

For client side you can find client id of textbox like this :

```
'<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).FindControl("textDateSent").ClientID %>'
```

Reference [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1129062/1531476)

Hope this helps !

Comment: Actually the code is working in C# side. I have updated the full code in the question of how i am accessing the Text field in C#. It works. But it is not working in the ASPX page. This line shows error `<a href="javascript:NewCssCal('<%=text_master_dateedit.ClientID %>','DDMMYYYY')"><img id="Img1" alt="Pick a Date" src="Images/cal.png" width="25" height="25" style="vertical-align:middle;" /></a>`

Comment: I changed to this `<a href="javascript:NewCssCal('<%# ((gv)Container).FindControl("text_master_dateedit").ClientID %>','DDMMYYYY')"><img id="Img1" alt="Pick a Date" src="Images/cal.png" width="25" height="25" style="vertical-align:middle;" /></a>` but i am getting this error `CS0118: 'MasterPage.gv' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'`. MasterPage is the name of the aspx page.

Comment: Ok ok done.. Just now changed it is working :) Thank you. +1